# Custom Taxonomy Taxonomies of Same Name point to first created URL

Tags: custom-post-types, categories, custom-taxonomy

I created a Custom Post type and in that custom post type have a hierarchical taxonomy (categories).

Here's an example of the categories I made:

```
Hats
 - Mens
 - Womens

Shoes
 - Mens
 - Womens
```

The problem is that when I go to the "Mens" sub-category of the "Shoes" Main category it goes to the Mens category of the "Hats" category, i'm guessing it's because the URL of the two is the same.

What is the best way around this problem?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is a problem with wordpress that happened to me as well. If the titles of 2 terms (even if they are from different taxonomy), wordpress will not create another term in the database, instead link the previous term to taxonomy. If you look in your database, you'll find only 1 term with title "Mens" which will be a child of both Hats & Shoes. Also if you try to change the title/slug of one of those terms, wordpress will change the corresponding term under other taxonomy too. You can't separate them like this right now

Interestingly, if the terms you created were "Mens" & "mens", wordpress takes the slug of the 2nd to be "mens-2" & then it works as normal. I don't know if it's intentional but this thing was very frustrating the first time i found out.

Comment: Yeah it is frustrating, I discovered with custom taxomonmies you can use this function: get_term_link( $term->slug, $taxonomyName ); it actually works and solved my problem.  With regular wordpress categories it might work as well I haven't tested it.

Comment: The main problem arises when in future you want to change one of their titles & sadly there's no way to do it. You can unlink one of them & recreate it but then you'll have to reassign all the posts.

Comment: Would that problem be avoided if I was able to find away to use the Term ID rather than slug? I tried $term->term_id but that didn't work and I also tried $term->id

Comment: won't work. title/slug/ID everything gets linked together. The only option is to unlink it using phpmyadmin or writing some custom wordpress code to overcome this kind of situation

Answer (score 0):

I just hit this problem with regards to trying to automatically clear out terms for a custom taxonomy using TSQL, where terms from my main categories taxonomy with the same name would be deleted when I was only trying to delete terms associated with my custom taxonomy.

In regards to the issue of the two taxonomies having the same URL, have you tried applying a rewrite rule in your call to register_taxonomy()? For instance, I've got a main category "Baby", which lives at /baby, and a custom taxonomy for polls, which uses the very same term, "Baby", but lives at /polls/cat/baby.

It looks like this:

```
register_taxonomy(  
  'poll_category',  
  array('poll'),  
  array(  
    'public' => true,
    'hierarchical' => true,  
    'label' => 'Poll Category',  
    'query_var' => 'poll_category',  
    'rewrite' => array("slug" => "polls/cat", 'with_front' => FALSE), 
  )  
);
```